# Как получить точный текущий таймкод? — или — Как интегрировать свои субтитры в чужой ролик на ютубе?

Tags: youtube

Делаю расширенние для ютуб которое будет показывать суббтитры не по две строчки, а по одному слову. Как оказалось ютуб хранит автоматические суббтитры в xml файле где указаны точные таймкоды каждого слова до милисекунды, и который можно получить просто включив субтитры. Теперь стоит вопрос как получить точный текущий таймкод что бы точно знать когда какое слово выводить? Ютуб же откуда то берёт это значение. Подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении двигаться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возвращает время в секундах и миллисекундах

```
ytplayer = document.getElementById("movie_player");
ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
```

Cм. [API](http://https/developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1)

Comment: в том то и дело что нужно миллисекундах

Comment: Секунды:Миллисекунды. Вот так 830.509728